# ignore workstations that are offline and resume

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBScript to help me remove local users from the local admins.  I can't seem to get it to ignore workstations that are not on the network.

Is there a way to ignore workstations that are not found and have it continue to the next line under the `computers.txt` file?

For example, say PC1 and PC3 are found but PC2 is not found I want it to ignore not found workstations and continue until the end of the list of computers.

I've tried `On Error Resume Next` (didnt work), and I tried `Const ForReading = 1, Const ForAppending = 8, Const OverwriteExisting = True` (didnt work either).

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\adminScript\computers.txt")

strComputer = objFile.ReadLine

Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators")
For Each objUser In objGroup.Members
  If objUser.Name <> "Administrator" AND objUser.Name <> "Domain Admins" AND objUser.Name <> "G_SCCMAgent" AND objUser.Name <> "User" Then
    Wscript.Echo objUser.Name    
    objGroup.Remove(objUser.ADsPath)
  End If
Next    

wscript.Echo "I am done!"
```

Comment: Hi, please remove your comment and add the code to your question, in a code tag

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief `On Error Resume Next` doesn't magically make errors go away. Neither does defining symbolic constants for parameters of the `OpenTextFile` method.

If you want to skip over computers that aren't available you need to actually test the availability of each computer. A common way to do this is the [`Win32_PingStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

isAvailable = False
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address='" & strComputer & "'"
For Each res In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If res.StatusCode = 0 Then isAvailable = True
Next

If isAvailable Then
  'modify administrators group
End If
```

Also, you probably need to process the content of `computers.txt` in a loop. Your current code reads only the first line. To process more than one line from the file use something like this:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\adminScript\computers.txt")
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine

  '...
Loop
objFile.Close
```